# ¡No repetir un dato en el select en filas diferentes!

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdo

#La idea principal que estado trabajando. Que al momento de seleccionar una patente x del select en la primera fila. Al agregar una segunda fila aparezca bloqueada la patente de la primera fila. Lo ideal es que no se vuelvan a repetir dentro la tabla la misma patente.

#Esta primera linea de código me ayuda agregar una nueva fila a la tabla

```
<script>

   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#AgregarFila").click(function(){
        var TablaKilometraje = document.getElementById("tablaprueba");
        $("#tablaprueba").append("<tr>"+TablaKilometraje.rows[0].innerHTML+"</tr>");//1
        $('.borrar').off().click(function(e) {
            $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove();//2
        });
    });   
});  
</script>
```

#Esta linea ayuda a cargar los datos en el select. Si agrego una fila en el select me mostrara todo los datos. Si agrego otra fila me seguirá mostrando los datos en el select

```
       <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
           const select = document.getElementById('id_tracto');
           function CargarPatente() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Cargar_Datos_Kilometraje/Datos_Tracto_Kilometraje.php',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                const patente=(response)
                const options= document.createElement("option");
                  patente.forEach(departamento => {
                  const option = new Option(departamento.patentedata , departamento.iddata)
                  select.append(option)

                })
            }
        })
    }
    CargarPatente() 

    })
</script>
```

#Este es el html donde me muestra la tabla

```
    <div class="encabezado_0">
      <p>REGISTRO DE KILOMETRAJE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="registro">
      <form class="row g-3 needs-validation" method="POST" action="Registro_Kilometraje/Registrar_BBDD_Kilometraje.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
      <div class="form-group">

      <label>
      <div class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="AgregarFila"> AGREGAR NUEVA COLUMNA</div>
      </label>
      </div> 
        <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
            <tr>
                  <th scope="col">PATENTES</th>
                  <th scope="col">FECHA KM</th>
                  <th scope="col">KM ANTERIOR</th>
                  <th scope="col">INGRESAR KM ACTUAL</th>
                  <th scope="col">INGRESO FECHA KM</th>
                  <th scope="col">DIF. KM</th>
                  <th scope="col">ELIMINAR</th>
            </tr>
</thead>
   <tbody id="tablaprueba">
      <tr  >
        <td class="col-sm-3">
          <select class="form-select id_tracto" id="id_tracto" name="id_tracto[]">
            <option value="">SELECCIONAR PATENTE</option>
          </select>
        </td>

           <td class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control fecha_kilometraje" id="fecha_kilometraje" name="fecha_kilometraje[]" value="" readonly/>
        </td>
          <!-- Corresponde al ultimo kilometraje registrado en la bbdd que puede ser por mant,reparacion o registro km -->
        <td class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control kilometraje_actual" id="kilometraje_actual" name="kilometraje_actual[]" value="" readonly/>
        </td>
          <!-- Corresponde al kilometraje que se va a ingresar por sistema-->
        <td class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="" class="form-control kmactual" id="kmactual" name="kmactual[]"required>
        </td>

         <td class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="date" class="form-control fecha_ingreso_km" id="fecha_ingreso_km" name="fecha_ingreso_km[]" required>
        </td>

         <td class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="" class="form-control difierencia_km" id="difierencia_km" name="difierencia_km[]" readonly>
        </td>

        <td class="col-sm-2">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger borrar">ELIMINAR</button>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

#Este codigo me ayuda a cargar unos datos en los input que necesito leer

```
 <script>
             $("#tablaprueba").on('change', 'select.id_tracto', function() {
              var $select = $(this), // Obtenemos el select modificado
              $tr = $select.closest('tr'), // Buscamos el tr del select
              valor = $select.val();

              $.ajax({   
              data : { valor : valor },
              url : 'Cargar_Datos_Kilometraje/Cargar_Valor_Kilometraje.php',   
              dataType : 'json',
              type:  'POST',
              success : function(json) {

              

              $tr.find("input.fecha_kilometraje").val(json.fecha_km_actual);
              $tr.find("input.kilometraje_actual").val(json.km_actual);
          
           
          

              },
            
              error : function(xhr, status) {
              alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
              }
              });
          
              });

              </script>
```

#Este parte nos ayuda a hacer un calculo y luego enviarlo al input correspondiente

```
              <script>

             $("#tablaprueba").on('change', 'input.kmactual', function() {
            var contenido = document.getElementsByClassName("kilometraje_actual")[0].value;

            var $select = $(this), // Obtenemos el select modificado
            $tr = $select.closest('tr'), // Buscamos el tr del select
            valor = $select.val();


            if (parseInt(valor)>parseInt(contenido)) {

            var total= valor-contenido;
            $tr.find("input.difierencia_km").val(total);
            } else {
            MENSAJE = "EL KILOMETRAJE ACTUAL TIENE QUE SER MAYOR QUE EL KILOMETRAJE ANTERIOR ..!!";
            $("#mensaje").html(MENSAJE);
            $("#modalMensaje").modal('show');
          } 



              });
              </script>
```

Comment: Tu código aún esta muy verde para poderte dar una respuesta. Necesitamos ver como agregas nuevos registros y eso no lo muestras en tu pregunta. De ese modo, al agregar el nuevo registro podremos deshabilitar la patente usada o bien eliminarla. Mientras no avances en eso esta pregunta no tiene respuesta, lo siento.

Comment: @masterguru voy a editar el codigo estimado

Comment: @masterguru estimado agregue el codigo que me envio y funciono de maravillas. Quería pedirle algún consejo para mejorar mi programación me falta mucho por aprender y le agradecería un tips. Bendiciones estimado

Comment: Me alegro que te funcione. Si mi respuesta cumple con tu pregunta deberias aceptarla para que tu pregunta no quede eternamente pendiente, gracias. En cuando a consejos, visto tu código: 1) Aprende a indentar bien el código, es un esfuerzo considerable pero se leerá mejor por ti y cualquier otro. 2) Para pruebas rápidas en javascript, css y/o html aprende a usar https://jsfiddle.net y leer de su consola (llevo poco más de 3 meses aquí y no sabia javascript y gracias a esa página empecé a contestar y saber depurar) 3) Intenta responder preguntas en este sitio, las que veas más fáciles primero

Comment: Eso es lo que yo hice y ahora he cogido mucha confianza usando javascript, el cual llevaba muchos años evitando porque no sabia cómo depurar nada y me parecia horroroso (yo solo programaba en PHP puro y HTML básicamente antes de entrar aquí). En cuanto al punto (1) puedes usar jsfiddle.net para pegar tu código y luego pulsar sobre el enlace "Tidy" que indenta bien lo que pongas. En cuanto al punto (3), será duro, te costará responder a tiempo antes que los demás, pero al plantearte y entender preguntas de otros y ver respuestas aceptadas aprenderás mucho e irás ganando velocidad y conocimiento

Comment: Eso creo que se debe a esta linea: `var contenido = document.getElementsByClassName("kilometraje_actual")[0].value;` en la cual le estas diciendo que coja siempre el primer elemento con la clase `kilometraje_actual` pues se lo indicas con el `[0]`. Quizás podrias solucionarlo buscando primero el número de indice de la ultima fila con algo así como `indice = (TablaKilometraje.rows.length-1)` y luego sustituir el `[0]` por `[indice]`.  Pero repito, si con eso no lo consigues, mejor que hagas una nueva pregunta para ese problema específico.

Comment: @masterguru gracias estimado mañana voy a intentarlo. Te comento. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es mi propuesta, a ver que te parece. Realiza estos cambios:

1. Dentro de la función `CargarPatente`, donde pones esto:

```
      patente.forEach(departamento => {
        const option = new Option(departamento.patentedata, departamento.iddata)
```

cámbialo por esto:

```
      let i=1
      patente.forEach(departamento => {
        const option = new Option(departamento.patentedata, departamento.iddata)
        option.setAttribute("class", "patente"+i);
        i++
```

de esta forma, usando [setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) vamos a agregar una clase a cada **option** correspondiente al número generado dinámicamente en la variable **i** durante la iteración de los ciclos del **forEach**, que tendrá nombres como `patente1`, `patente2`, y así sucesivamente. De esta forma podremos después referenciarnos a todos ellos más facilmente.

2. Dentro del evento **change** del elemento `#tablaprueba` donde pones esto:

```
    valor = $select.val()
```

pon esto:

```
    valor = $select.val()
    previo = $select.data("prev")
    $select.data("prev",valor);
    $('.patente' + valor).attr('disabled','disabled')
    $('.patente' + previo).removeAttr('disabled')
```

De esta forma, mediante el método [data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) de jquery estamos almacenando el valor actual en la clave `prev`, el cual, si existe, recuperamos antes en la variable `previo` para su uso posterior. Esto es importante porque puede darse el caso que después de seleccionar una patente luego queramos seleccionar otra de nuevo en el mismo `select`.

Después lo que hacemos es, gracias a las clases que hemos agregado antes, deshabilitamos el option seleccionado agregando el atributo `disabled` usando [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/), y habilitamos el option cambiado que ya no se usa para que pueda ser usado en otro `select` mediante la eliminación del atributo `disabled` usando [removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeattr/).

Ya nos diras si te ha funcionado.

Aquí te dejo un snippet (algo trucado porque no puedo hacer la petición ajax) funcional para que lo puedas ver y ejecutar:

```js
$("#AgregarFila").click(function() {
  var TablaKilometraje = document.getElementById("tablaprueba");
  $("#tablaprueba").append("<tr>" + TablaKilometraje.rows[0].innerHTML + "</tr>"); //1
  $('.borrar').off().click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove(); //2
  });
});

const select = document.getElementById('id_tracto');

function CargarPatente() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'Cargar_Datos_Kilometraje/Datos_Tracto_Kilometraje.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(response) {
      const patente = (response)
      const options = document.createElement("option");
      let i = 1
      patente.forEach(departamento => {
        const option = new Option(departamento.patentedata, departamento.iddata)
        option.setAttribute("class", "patente" + i);
        i++
        select.append(option)
      })
    }
  })
}
CargarPatente()

var sel = $("#sel");
sel.data("prev", sel.val());

$("#tablaprueba").on('change', 'select.id_tracto', function() {
  var $select = $(this), // Obtenemos el select modificado
    $tr = $select.closest('tr'), // Buscamos el tr del select
    valor = $select.val()
  previo = $select.data("prev")
  $select.data("prev", valor);
  $('.patente' + valor).attr('disabled', 'disabled')
  $('.patente' + previo).removeAttr('disabled')
  $.ajax({
    data: {
      valor: valor
    },
    url: 'Cargar_Datos_Kilometraje/Cargar_Valor_Kilometraje.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(json) {
      $tr.find("input.fecha_kilometraje").val(json.fecha_km_actual);
      $tr.find("input.kilometraje_actual").val(json.km_actual);

    },

    error: function(xhr, status) {
      alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
    }
  });

});



$("#tablaprueba").on('change', 'input.kmactual', function() {
  var contenido = document.getElementsByClassName("kilometraje_actual")[0].value;

  var $select = $(this), // Obtenemos el select modificado
    $tr = $select.closest('tr'), // Buscamos el tr del select
    valor = $select.val();


  if (parseInt(valor) > parseInt(contenido)) {

    var total = valor - contenido;
    $tr.find("input.difierencia_km").val(total);
  } else {
    MENSAJE = "EL KILOMETRAJE ACTUAL TIENE QUE SER MAYOR QUE EL KILOMETRAJE ANTERIOR ..!!";
    $("#mensaje").html(MENSAJE);
    $("#modalMensaje").modal('show');
  }



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="encabezado_0">
      <p>REGISTRO DE KILOMETRAJE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="registro">
      <form class="row g-3 needs-validation" method="POST" action="Registro_Kilometraje/Registrar_BBDD_Kilometraje.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
      <div class="form-group">

      <label>
      <div class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="AgregarFila"> AGREGAR NUEVA COLUMNA</div>
      </label>
      </div> 
        <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
            <tr>
                  <th scope="col">PATENTES</th>
                  <th scope="col">FECHA KM</th>
                  <th scope="col">KM ANTERIOR</th>
                  <th scope="col">INGRESAR KM ACTUAL</th>
                  <th scope="col">INGRESO FECHA KM</th>
                  <th scope="col">DIF. KM</th>
                  <th scope="col">ELIMINAR</th>
            </tr>
</thead>
   <tbody id="tablaprueba">
      <tr  >
        <td class="col-sm-3">
          <select class="form-select id_tracto" id="id_tracto" name="id_tracto[]">
            <option value="">SELECCIONAR PATENTE</option>
            <option class="patente1" value="1">PATENTE 1</option>
            <option class="patente2" value="2">PATENTE 2</option>
            <option class="patente3" value="3">PATENTE 3</option>
            <option class="patente4" value="4">PATENTE 4</option>
          </select>
        </td>

           <td class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control fecha_kilometraje" id="fecha_kilometraje" name="fecha_kilometraje[]" value="" readonly/>
        </td>
          <!-- Corresponde al ultimo kilometraje registrado en la bbdd que puede ser por mant,reparacion o registro km -->
        <td class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control kilometraje_actual" id="kilometraje_actual" name="kilometraje_actual[]" value="" readonly/>
        </td>
          <!-- Corresponde al kilometraje que se va a ingresar por sistema-->
        <td class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="" class="form-control kmactual" id="kmactual" name="kmactual[]"required>
        </td>

         <td class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="date" class="form-control fecha_ingreso_km" id="fecha_ingreso_km" name="fecha_ingreso_km[]" required>
        </td>

         <td class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="" class="form-control difierencia_km" id="difierencia_km" name="difierencia_km[]" readonly>
        </td>

        <td class="col-sm-2">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger borrar">ELIMINAR</button>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: @masterguro gracias estimado. Mañana lo probare  muchas gracias por tu tiempo se agradece mucho

Comment: muchas gracias por la solución. Sabe tengo un pequeño problema . Por que al agregar una nueva columna me toma el primer km anterior y no el segundo. saludos

Comment: No se a que te refieres... mi respuesta se centraba en los select, y no parece que ese problema que tienes ahora tenga que ver con ello.  Si es algo nuevo mejor que formules una nueva pregunta porque mirando el codigo actual me cuesta entender lo que significa para ti eso de ***me toma el primer km anterior y no el segundo***

Comment: Estimado esta todo bien. Lo que sucede por ejemplo la primera fila selecciono una patente se me cargara la fecha, km anterior. con la primera fila no tengo problema. al agregar la segunda fila. selecciono una patente me carga la fecha y km anterior pero al momento de ingresar el nuevo kilometraje me hace la comparación con la primera fila. debería ser con la segunda fila. saludos